# Action of the Symplectic Group on Siegel Upper Half Plane

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Given $G= \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix} \in Sp_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ one can define an action on the symmetric $n \times n$ complex matrices with positive definite imaginary part by writing $GZ=(A+BZ)(C+DZ)^{-1}$. I think it should be any easy exercise to show this action is well-defined but for some reason I'm having trouble. In particular, it's not clear to me that $C+DZ$ is invertible and that $(A+BZ)(C+DZ)^{-1}$ has the desired properties. Perhaps someone could give me a hint?

Comment: Any introductory book on Theta functions, Siegel modular forms, or hyperbolic space will have the argument.  See for instance H. Klingen, introductory lectures on Siegel modular forms.  The idea is to let $P=A+BZ$ and $Q = C+DZ$ and derive the identity $P^T\overline{Q}-Q^T\overline{P} = 2i\Im(Z).$  From this identity you can derive $X^T \Im(Z) \overline{X}=0$ for any $X$ satisfying $QX=0$.  Now use positive definiteness of $\Im(Z)$.